# How can we add a second initialization condition to a for loop in java processing?

Tags: java, for-loop, processing

```
int numPile=21;
int numPlayer1=10;
int numPlayer2=10;

void setup()
{
    size(500,500);
}

void draw()
{
    drawMatchPile(20,30,10,40,numPile);
    drawMatchPile(20,height-100,10,40,numPlayer1);
    drawMatchPile(width/2,height-100,10,40,numPlayer2);
}
        
void drawMatchPile(int posX, int posY,int matchW, int matchH,int numPile)
{
    matchW= 10;
    matchH = 50;

    int dist;
    ellipseMode(RECT); 
           
    for(numPile= numPile+1; numPile > 0; numPile --)
    {
        for(dist =1; (dist < numPile); dist++);
        {
            fill(255, 0, 0); 
            ellipse( dist * posX, posY, matchW+2, matchH * 0.4); 
            fill(#D3C11C); 
            rect( dist * posX, posY+matchH * 0.35,matchW,matchH); 
        }
    }
}
```

**> Goal: draw rows of match sticks on different x Positions using ONE for loop**.
**> //How can we draw matches at xPosition = width/2 without changing the test (numPile variable)?**

> // -so long as dist < numPile the matches are drawn. Works when xPosition = 20.
> // 21 matches are drawn at xPostion = 20, yPosition = 30.
> // 10 matches are drawn at xPostion = 20, yPosition = height- 100.
> **// 0 matches are drawn at xPosition = width/2, yPostion = height -100.**

> //The function is called three times in draw. The posX variable is initialized in draw, and passed on to the for-loop through the posX parameter of drawMatchPile. All Functions depend on the same posX variable. The posX is multiplied by the variable (dist) within the for loop, as long as dist < numPile, it will draw the shape again. However if posX is equal to width/2, then posX = 250, and the test is no longer true.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to format your code (your IDE should help you with that) - without indentation, it's really hard to read the code. (It's also invalid code in various ways... again, it's hard to help without seeing the actual code.)

Comment: Sorry about that. Should work now.

Comment: Definitely better, but still hard to read due to lack of indentation.

Comment: You can simply list the initializations in comma separated list (at least when they have the same type):
    for (int j = 0, d=2 ; j < board[0].length; j++) {

Comment: Full sample for 2 variables for (int j = 0, d=2; j < board[0].length && d < 100; j++, d++)